# How to make date intervals from a list of date

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

How to make date intervals from a list of date (Group by columns A and C, the date range consists of a continuous date sequence):

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have a SQL Server 2005 instance to test against, but this works under SQL Server 2008.  It uses a couple of [Common Table Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and a [Windowing Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
--demo setup
DECLARE @TestData TABLE (
    ColA varchar(10)
    ,ColB datetime
    ,ColC char(1)
    )

insert into @TestData (ColA,ColB,ColC) values ('Cat','2019-01-02','T');
insert into @TestData (ColA,ColB,ColC) values ('Cat','2019-01-03' ,'T');
insert into @TestData (ColA,ColB,ColC) values ('Cat','2019-01-04' ,'G');
insert into @TestData (ColA,ColB,ColC) values ('Cat','2019-01-06' ,'G');
insert into @TestData (ColA,ColB,ColC) values ('Cat','2019-01-07' ,'G');
insert into @TestData (ColA,ColB,ColC) values ('Cat','2019-01-08' ,'G');
insert into @TestData (ColA,ColB,ColC) values ('Cat','2019-02-07' ,'G');
insert into @TestData (ColA,ColB,ColC) values ('Cat','2019-02-08' ,'G');
insert into @TestData (ColA,ColB,ColC) values ('Cat','2019-02-09' ,'T');
insert into @TestData (ColA,ColB,ColC) values ('Dog','2019-03-09' ,'T');
;
--solution
WITH mycte1
AS (
    SELECT *
        ,DATEADD(DAY, - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY ColA,ColC ORDER BY [ColB]
                ), [ColB]) AS grp
    FROM @TestData
    )
,mycte2 as
(
SELECT ColA
    ,min([ColB]) AS [Start]
    ,max([ColB]) AS [End]
    ,ColC
FROM mycte1
GROUP BY ColA,ColC
    ,grp
)
select * from mycte2
ORDER BY ColA, Start
```

---

```
| ColA | Start      | End        | ColC |
|------|------------|------------|------|
| Cat  | 2019-01-02 | 2019-01-03 | T    |
| Cat  | 2019-01-04 | 2019-01-04 | G    |
| Cat  | 2019-01-06 | 2019-01-08 | G    |
| Cat  | 2019-02-07 | 2019-02-08 | G    |
| Cat  | 2019-02-09 | 2019-02-09 | T    |
| Dog  | 2019-03-09 | 2019-03-09 | T    |
```

Comment: @McNets - thanks for the update.

Comment: @McNets What causes a problem? CTE?

Comment: @ScottHodgin Try to convert CTE to subquery.

Comment: @Akina - Date is not a supported data type in 2005

Comment: @Akina and you need a single `insert ...values` for each line. Look at my edit

Comment: This is source data problems, not query ones...

Comment: @Akina some window functions are not supported on 2005, LAG/LEAD

Comment: @McNets Yes, I already looked.But Scott don't use them.

Comment: @Akina we are still maintaining a legacy 2005 in production, I simply checked Scott code due he said "I don't have a SQL Server 2005 instance to test against.".